# How to change column sorting type after after button click? [jQuery,DataTables]

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data in column like "firstValue secondValue". This data must be in one column (I cant make two columns). When I set sorting, it sort by firstValue and secondValue. Now after some event I want to change to sort data by secondValue (ignore firstValue). After another event I want to sort by firstValue. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but I just came upon the same problem. The solution involves a combination of [custom sorting](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) and [altering the table settings in the event handler](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/542/dynamically-change-idisplaylength/p1).

Some code to make it more concrete:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "secondValue-pre": function ( a ) {
        var parts = a.split(' ')[1];        
    },
    "secondValue-asc": function ( a, b ) { return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0)); },
    "secondValue-desc": function ( a, b ) { return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0)); }
});

var $myTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  "aoColumns": [
    null, //your column containing "firstValue secondValue"
    null,
  ]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.something').click( function () {
        var oSettings = $myTable.fnSettings();
        oSettings.aoColumns[0].sType = 'secondValue';
    });
});
```

I'm sure there are numerous ways to improve this code, but it should get you started.